# Issue with Model driven in struts for a PUT request?

Tags: java, struts2, put, model-driven

I'm making a PUT request with `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I'm not able to map the form body elements to my ModelDriven action class (`User`).

Here is a sample request:

PUT: `http://www.xyz.com/account/22424?userName=xyz&email=xyz@email.com`
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Here is the code:**

**1) Modeldriven action class:**

```java
public class User {

    private String email;
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**2) Controller:**

```java
public class AccountController implements ModelDriven <User> {

    private String id;
    private User user = new User();

    public String update() {
        user.getUserName(); // Fails, returns NULL. (Expected "xyz")
    }

    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To map the model to your form you should implement the [model driven](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html) interface that you already did and configure action to use the [model driven interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven-interceptor.html).

Also make sure that the request content correspond to its content type and encoding.